# VS2015. _ftprintf don't work well

Tags: printf, visual-studio-2015

I've got the followings sentences that work fine in VS2013 but not in VS2015. Do you know why?

```
FILE    *m_fichero;
CString  línea;
int      a = 23;

_tfopen_s(&m_fichero, _T("fichero"), _T("w"));

línea = _T("Hola caracola");

_ftprintf(m_fichero, _T("%s. %d. %s\n"), linea, a, _T("Adios"));
```

The file created is

'H'. 123. Adios

Comment: "don't work" and "work fine in VS2013 but not in VS2015" don't actually give us much information - what happens? Does it fail to compile? (If so, *what* messages are given?) Do you get an error at runtime? (If so, *what* error?). Does it cause your computer to spontaneously combust?

Comment: No, there isn't any error in compilation time and there isn't error in runtime. apparently run fine, but ... when I see the output file, I see that file is completed incorrectly, and I don't why. I tried to replace the "CString" variable with another one like "char []", and now yes, run fine, and nor I know why. The application is compiled with UNICODE. Sincerely, I think is an error of Visual Studio 2015 preview.               Many thanks in advance

Comment: More clues. If I replace "s" with "S" works perfectly: _T("%S. %d. %s"). Why? I think is an error of this version